# ¿Inicializar una lista en mi bean con un solo registro?

Tags: jsf, primefaces, jpa

Buena tarde, mi consulta es la siguiente tengo un bean que me inicializa en su    metodo tres listas.

```
 @PostConstruct
 public void inicializarBean() {

    ordenTrabajoRemisionList = ordentrabajoRemisionFacade.findAll();
    ordenTrabajoList = ordentrabajoFacade.findAll();
    tipoRemisionList = tipoRemisionFacade.findAll();       


    tipoRemisionSeleccionada = new TipoRemision();
    ordentrabajoRemision = new OrdentrabajoRemision();
    productoRemision = new ProductoRemision();
    materialRemision = new MaterialRemision();
    ordentrabajo = new Ordentrabajo();

    fechaActual = Calendar.getInstance().getTime();

}
```

esas listas se muestran en un datatable y se filtran mediante cualquier columna, la pregunta es como inicializar la lista sin que me arroje todos los registros en el datatable si no que los pueda filtrar en la columna de ID y me haga la consulta especifica y me arroje una unica fila.

Comment: Explica un poco más claro lo que necesitas.

Answer (score 0):

El problema no está de lado de JSF, sino de cómo inicializas la lista. Por lo visto, estás usando el método `findAll` de tus fachadas, por lo cual se entiende que estás recuperando todos los elementos de tu entidad o tabla. Lo que debes hacer es crear un nuevo método que permita traer los resultados por páginas, es decir, traer solo una parte de todos los componentes que deberías traer, y usar eso para mostrar en tu primera página.

Ejemplo:

```
public class OrdenTrabajoRemisionFacade {
    public List<OrdenTrabajoRemission> findPage(int offset, int limit) {
        //implementación que dependerá de cómo obtienes los datos desde bd
    }
}

//...

@PostConstruct
public void inicializarBean() {
    //ejemplo
    ordenTrabajoRemisionList = ordentrabajoRemisionFacade.findPage(0, 10);
    //hacer algo similar para tu caso
    ordenTrabajoList = ordentrabajoFacade.findAll();
    tipoRemisionList = tipoRemisionFacade.findAll();       

    tipoRemisionSeleccionada = new TipoRemision();
    ordentrabajoRemision = new OrdentrabajoRemision();
    productoRemision = new ProductoRemision();
    materialRemision = new MaterialRemision();
    ordentrabajo = new Ordentrabajo();

    fechaActual = new Date(); //Calendar.getInstance().getTime();
}
```

Una sugerencia mía, puedes ir trayendo más resultado mediante un evento ajax para dar la noción de que hay más resultados. Esto con JSF por sí solo no se puede lograr (tan fácilmente), lo mejor sería usar una librería como [Omnifaces](http://showcase.omnifaces.org/) y  o [lazy loading](https://www.primefaces.org/showcase/ui/data/datatable/lazy.xhtml) de [PrimeFaces](https://www.primefaces.org/).